# How to count the number of characters in a command line argument by using and creating a function

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, strlen

I am having trouble understanding how to create a function to count the characters in a command line argument. It only has to compute the result in the 'my_strlen()' function, but to print the result out in main().
I am very new to C, but here is my code so far;

```
int my_strlen(  char string[]);
{
     strcpy(string, argv[1];
     return 1;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argv != 2)
  {
    printf("You must run this program with an argument\n");
    return 2;
  }
  printf("%d", strlen(string);
  return 0;
}
```

So as you can see, I am pretty confused, I also didn't know how to store the value of strlen(string) to call it later as its own integer.

Comment: Where is `string` in `main()`, You should use `strlen(argv[1]);`. And there are several other errors in the code: `if(argv != 2)` should be `if(argc != 2)` and there is no library function by name `strcopy`, it is called `strcpy`.

Comment: @CodyGray **C** ommand **L** ine **A** rgument, I guess. But the question is still pretty confusing.

Comment: Also for `if(argv != 2)` you mean `argc` not `argv`?

Comment: @CodyGray : OP trying to frame his own Abbreviation, it is Command Line Arguments

Comment: Sorry, no I wasn't attempting to create my own abbreviation, I saw it on another question in stack.
@Jayesh Oh, yes, I did mean to use argc. As I said, I am very new.

Comment: @XavierDassp-No problem BOY,you'll learn from these mistakes only! In this way you'll learn the correct way of coding...

Comment: Well, you have some scope issues to start -- you use `string` in main when it's defined in the other function, and `argv[1]` in the other function when it's only declared in main. Try passing `argv[1]` to the function, which in turn calculates the length of a character array.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild I am not sure what you mean by having `string` in main. I thought I had it with `strlen(string)`?

Comment: I meant there is no `string` variable declared in `main()` or globally.

Comment: `argc` stores the count of arguments. Also include `string.h` and `stdio.h`. Where is string variable? You are not calling `my_strlen` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this simple code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Function to calculate length of given string */
int my_strlen(char *input_string)
{
    /* Loop through all the characters in the string till null-terminator */
    int i;
    for(i=0; input_string[i] != '\0'; i++);
    return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int length = -1;
  if(argc != 2) /* Check the number of command line arguments */
  {
    printf("You must run this program with an argument\n");
    return 2;
  }
  else
  {
    /* Your function to calculate length of the string */
    length = my_strlen(argv[1]); 
    printf("Length of command line argument is: %d\n", length);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here 
`argv[0]` is program name.
`argv[1]` is the argument to the program.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand mostly how this works. But I am a little confused as to how `string[i]` works?

Comment: `string[i]` will give you the character in `string` at `i`th location.